# Error while initializing FMOD

Tags: c++, winapi, fmod

Im having a weird issue while initializing FMOD, FMOD enters in some kind of 'infinite loop' and the program stops. What i'm doing wrong?
This is the function:

```
FMOD::System   *fmodsyst = 0;
FMOD::Sound    *sound = 0;
FMOD::Channel  *channel = 0;
FMOD_RESULT     result = FMOD_OK;
unsigned int    version = 0;
unsigned int    soundlength = 0;
bool            dspenabled = false;
void           *extradriverdata = 0;
unsigned int    recordpos = 0;
unsigned int    recorddelta = 0;
unsigned int    minrecorddelta = (unsigned int)-1;
unsigned int    lastrecordpos = 0;
unsigned int    samplesrecorded = 0;
unsigned int    playpos = 0;
float           smootheddelta = 0;
int recordrate = 0;
int recordchannels = 0;
unsigned int adjustedlatency = 0;
unsigned int driftthreshold = 0;
FMOD_CREATESOUNDEXINFO exinfo;

bool Basics::InitializeFMOD()
{
    FMOD_RESULT    result;
    unsigned int   version;
    result = FMOD::System_Create(&fmodsyst);
    FMOD_ERRCHECK(result);
    result = fmodsyst->getVersion(&version);
    FMOD_ERRCHECK(result);
    if (version < FMOD_VERSION)
    {
        return false;
    }
    result = fmodsyst->init(100, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, extradriverdata); //this is the line which crashes the .dll
    FMOD_ERRCHECK(result);

    result = fmodsyst->getRecordDriverInfo(0, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, &recordrate, 0, &recordchannels);
    FMOD_ERRCHECK(result);

    adjustedlatency = (recordrate * LATENCY_MS) / 1000;
    driftthreshold = adjustedlatency / 2;

    memset(&exinfo, 0, sizeof(FMOD_CREATESOUNDEXINFO));
    exinfo.cbsize = sizeof(FMOD_CREATESOUNDEXINFO);
    exinfo.numchannels = recordchannels;
    exinfo.format = FMOD_SOUND_FORMAT_PCM16;
    exinfo.defaultfrequency = recordrate;
    exinfo.length = exinfo.defaultfrequency * sizeof(short)* exinfo.numchannels * 5; /* 5 second buffer, doesnt really matter how big this is, but not too small of course. */

    result = fmodsyst->createSound(0, FMOD_LOOP_NORMAL | FMOD_OPENUSER, &exinfo, &sound);
    FMOD_ERRCHECK(result);

    result = fmodsyst->recordStart(0, sound, true);
    FMOD_ERRCHECK(result);

    result = sound->getLength(&soundlength, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_PCM);
    FMOD_ERRCHECK(result);

    return true;
}
```

Also the function FMOD_ERRCHECK doesnt say anything.

Comment: Which actual line is causing the problem?  Try reducing your code the a short self-contained example, just a main with the initialization code in it and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: this is the line which is causing the problem: result = fmodsyst->init(100, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, extradriverdata); //this is the line which crashes the .dll - I applied some debugging with the WriteToLog function and that is the part were it gets stucked.

Comment: You have provided no definition for `extradriverdata`, but you have provided much irrelevant code. Please edit your question down to the minimum _complete_ code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is, i just edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you want FMOD_STUDIO_INIT_NORMAL instead of FMOD_INIT_NORMAL because you are, in fact, initializing the Studio component and not the low level audio system (at least not via that pointer).

We may have different versions, as mine requires an extra parameter:

```
_pAudioSystem->initialize(32, FMOD_STUDIO_INIT_NORMAL, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, nullptr);
```